# How to select posts from wordpress db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to read posts from my wordpress website's db in order to show in another format. But when I check the table there are multiple records for a single post.

My query brings all edit rows for just one post. So there are many rows for just one post. I want to handle last edited and

It adds a new row after each edition. What would be my `SELECT` query for getting all posts with last edit? In other words what is wordpress' querying method to achieve this?

I have tried the following query with help of @Khushboo, but it results multiple rows for just one post again.

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON  p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.post_type = 'post'
AND p.post_date < NOW( )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :-

```
<?php

 $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 ?>
```

For more details, please check http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Comment: remove AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email'

Comment: then it brings multiple records still

Comment: It will display all published posts

Comment: you can use DISTINCT for ID

Comment: I have used DISTINCT and everything looks OK for now.